# Why aren't my relations loaded?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following entities:

```
public abstract class Meter
{
    public int MeterId { get; set; }
    public string EANNumber { get; set; }
    public string MeterNumber { get; set; }
    public abstract void AddReading(CounterReading reading);
}

public abstract class ElectricityMeter : Meter { }

public class SingleElectricityMeter : ElectricityMeter
{
    private Counter _counter = new Counter();
    public virtual Counter Counter
    {
        get { return _counter; }
        set { _counter = value; }
    }

    public override void AddReading(CounterReading reading)
    {
        Counter.Readings.Add(reading);
    }
}

public class Counter
{
    public int CounterId { get; set; }

    private ObservableCollection<CounterReading> _readings = new ObservableCollection<CounterReading>();

    public virtual ObservableCollection<CounterReading> Readings
    {
        get { return _readings; }
        set { _readings = value; }
    }


    [NotMapped]
    public CounterReading CurrentReading
    {
        get
        {
            return Readings.MaxBy(m => m.Reading);
        }
    }
}
```

When I set the `Counter` relation in runtime, everything works perfect.
When I try to load the saved data, my `Counter` object isn't loaded (it's the default `Counter`, and not the one with the data from my database).

Is this still because I'm using inheritance in my `Meter`?
My database looks decent enough with foreign keys:
[image]

**Edit**
Retrieving other nested entities works without problem.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried it without using inheritance in your ElectricityMeter? Also, why are you using ObservableCollection instead of a plain Collection?

Comment: @danludwig I haven't yet tried it without inheritance, but I hope the result will stay the same because using inheritance makes my life easier to write this application. I use ObservableCollection because that way I can let the UI update without writing any code myself.

Comment: Can you show us the code that retrieves the SingleElectricityMeter from the database?

Comment: @Dabblernl I get my `SingleElectricityMeter` via its property on another entity, which I get via `Context.Premises.First()`.

Comment: The related entitities are not loaded automatically, which is a good thing, otherwise you may pull in the entire database with just one query. Do some reading about Lazy or Explicit Loading. 'Context.Premises.Include(premise=>premise.Counter)' should do the trick.

Comment: @Dabblernl Lazy loading is enabled, because I can retrieve other properties multiple levels deep without any problem. See my update for an example.

Comment: Iam not sure if this related to your problem, but you now have a setup where a single Counter has Many Meters. Shouldn't that be the other way around? Or, if a Meter has a single Counter, why don't you inline it as a Complex Type?

Comment: @Dabblernl How can a Counter have multiple Meters? And what is inlining it as a complex type?

Comment: Remove the Id from the Counter and the foreign key to it from the Meter. This will turn the Counter into a Complex type. This too must not be initialized unless you deal with a new Meter.

Answer (score 3):

`SingleElectricityMeter.Counter` is a (reference) navigation property. In your code it is always initialized by

```
private Counter _counter = new Counter();
```

But you [shouldn't initialize reference properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20757594/861716). EF will think they're loaded and won't load them from the database. So just remove the initialization. But be careful...

The encapsulation of adding readings in the top-level class is a good idea from an OO point of view, but in the context of Entity Framework (or any ORM) it comes with a caveat. In order to make this work you always have to ensure that a `Meter` is read from the database including the `Counter` and its `Readings`:

```
db.Meters.Include(m => m.Counter.Readings)
```

As long as you do this, EF will be tracking all objects it needs in order to notice that `Readings` causes a change it should store in the database.

Also, by doing so it is safe to access `Counter.CurrentReading`. Otherwise this might trigger lazy loading (may not be bad, but can be inefficient) or cause an error if this happens after the context has been disposed.

Comment: If I shouldn't initialize reference properties, how will I use them when I have just created a new Meter and thus the Counter is still null?

Comment: You'll have to create a new Counter as well then. I don't see any other alternative.