# Entity Framework does not load related data when entities are not public

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6.1

I have two classes in console application.

`Person`:

```
 class Person {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }

        public override string ToString() {
            return Id + " " + FirstName + " " + LastName; 
        }
    }
```

and `Order`:

```
 class Order {
        //Id to domyslna nazwa na identyfikator -> klucz glowny
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Total { get; set; }
        public virtual Person Owner { get; set; }

        public override string ToString() {
            return Id + " " + Total;
        }
    }
```

My `dbContext` is:

```
    class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext {
        public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("Olek2") {
                Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
                Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;

        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }
       public static ApplicationDbContext Create() {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();

      }
}
```

I generated fresh database by `update-database`.

In `Main` method I try to fetch `Person` and then access person's orders but I get null pointer exception on `p1.Orders.Count()`. I made properties virtual, also enabled lazy loading, i don't know where the problem is.

```
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext(); 
        Person p1 = context.Persons.Find(1);
        Console.WriteLine(p1); // THIS WORKS
        Console.WriteLine(context.Orders.Count()); //THIS IS 1
        Console.WriteLine(p1.Orders.Count()); //EXCEPTION HERE 
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Also my `Seed` method:

```
protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context) {
        Person person = null;

        if (!context.Persons.Any()) {
             person = new Person() {  FirstName = "Alaaaaa", LastName = "Kowlaska" };
            context.Persons.AddOrUpdate(person);
        }
        if (!context.Orders.Any()) {
            context.Orders.AddOrUpdate(new Order() { Total = 100, Owner = person });
        }

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

**EDIT:**

I got a hunch that it has something to do with `public static ApplicationDbContext Create()`  has 0 references (VS2013 indicates that) in my console application(which fails).

In my ASP.NET-MVC(works fine) it was referenced by:

```
 public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Configure the db context and user manager to use a single instance per request
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);

        ....
       }
```

**EDIT2**
 I had a hunch it does not seem to be connected anyhow.

Comment: Have you tried adding an `include` clause for orders?

Comment: @PeterSmith I never had to use them. In other bigger project(ASP.NET-MVC 5) I've made more than 10 model classes with tens of associations, enabled lazyloading and used virtual keyword and I never encountered this problem. What should I change in code I posted? I don't understand reasons of the exception becuase EF should automatically load `order` when I ask for it -> this idea which stands for lazy loading.

Comment: Have you checked what's in the database? Your seed method will add an Order with a null Owner if a Person already existed. That said, Person.Orders should be empty rather than null in this case.

Comment: In your `Main` method, check your `context.Persons.Local`. Does it already have `Person` with id=1 before you're calling `Find(1)`?

Comment: @haim770`context.Persons.Local.Count()` returns 0 so it does not `context.Persons.Count()` returns 1 and I have only one person in the database.

Comment: You'll also want the DBSet collections to be virtual, i.e, `public virtual DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }`.

Comment: Are your `Person` and `Order` classes marked as `public`?

Comment: @haim770 NO :D That was the problem. Why they have to be public to make lazy loading work? Thank you! Please post an answer I'll accept it. Also do the `DbSets` have be `virtual` as @Dwright states? It works great without `virtual`  keyword, like this: `public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }`

Comment: @Yoda, maybe they don't *have* to be virtual, but that's the way EF itself generates them, if it autogenerates this kind of stuff.

Comment: @DWright I always use code first approach, I guess(after reading your comment)that it generates it virtual when we use schema or database first approach? Or is there a 3rd option to generate `DbSets` implicitly?

Comment: Right that's how it does it non-code first, so probably a good practice in code first to.

Comment: @Yoda, There is no reason to mark `DbSet<T>` properties as `virtual` unless you're going to override them in some derived type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your entities are not marked with the `public` modifier (which means by default the compiler will make them `internal`), EF will not be able to generate proxies for the entity type.

Looking at the [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data.Entity/System/Data/Objects/Internal/EntityProxyFactory.cs,577) of `EntityProxyFactory` (line 577):

```
private static bool CanProxyType(EntityType ospaceEntityType)
{
    TypeAttributes access = ospaceEntityType.ClrType.Attributes & TypeAttributes.VisibilityMask;

    ConstructorInfo ctor = ospaceEntityType.ClrType.GetConstructor(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.CreateInstance, null, Type.EmptyTypes, null);
    bool accessableCtor = ctor != null && (((ctor.Attributes & MethodAttributes.MemberAccessMask) == MethodAttributes.Public) ||
                                          ((ctor.Attributes & MethodAttributes.MemberAccessMask) == MethodAttributes.Family) ||
                                          ((ctor.Attributes & MethodAttributes.MemberAccessMask) == MethodAttributes.FamORAssem));

    return (!(ospaceEntityType.Abstract ||
             ospaceEntityType.ClrType.IsSealed ||
             typeof(IEntityWithRelationships).IsAssignableFrom(ospaceEntityType.ClrType) ||
             !accessableCtor) &&
             access == TypeAttributes.Public);
}
```

You can clearly notice the last line of `CanProxyType` checking whether the entity type is indeed `public`.

Now, since you don't initialize `Person.Orders` (in the constructor or anywhere else) and no proxy is involved to intercept the call to `Orders` (initialize it and detect the association to `Order.Person`), you end up with `Orders` being null and NRE is thrown.

Comment: Great answer. If I initilized Person.Orders in the constructor of `ApplicationDbContext` then it would also work?

Comment: @Yoda, Partially. You would simply get an empty `List<Order>` (or `HashSet<Order>`) with no related `Order` in it. It's only the Proxy that is able to detect that relationship for you and fill the data in it. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/20773057 for more info