# EntityFramework 6. How to get related objects?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have two and more related tables in my project.
And need to get related objects.

Here is what I did: http://pastebin.com/BbkT8zvd

And trying to get like this:

```
using (LocalContext _db = new LocalContext())
{
    var list = _db.Document.ToList();
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Name+ ": ");
        foreach (var item2 in item.Comment)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item2.CommentText);
        }
    }       
}
```

It returns no comments related with documents.

Tried Lazy, Eager and Explicit loading methods.

What should I correct in my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use eager loading for getting related entities, Eager loading is achieved by use of the Include method:

```
_db.Document.Include("Comment").ToList();
```

[More info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx)

**Update**: You don't need to initialize `Document` in the `Comment` class, Your `Comment` class should be like this:

```
public class Comment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int DocId { get; set; }
    public string CommentText { get; set; }
    public virtual Document Document { get; set; } 
}
```

`Document` class:

```
public class Document
{
    public Document()
    {
        this.Comment = new HashSet<Comment>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comment { get; set; } 
}
```

And the query:

```
var list = _db.Document.Include("Comment").ToList();
```

In this case all related comments will be loaded.

Comment: Initializing `Document` in `Comment`'s constructor is the key to this problem. It blocks relationship fixup. See also [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20757594/861716) that I updated to cover this case here.

Answer (score 2):

As I see in your codes, you have disabled lazy loading `Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;`. So you need include child items this way:

```
_db.Document.Include("Comment").ToList()
```

You can consider reading:

- [Entity Framework Loading Related Entitues](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx)
- [DbContextConfiguration.LazyLoadingEnabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbcontextconfiguration.lazyloadingenabled(v=vs.113).aspx#P:System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbContextConfiguration.LazyLoadingEnabled)

Comment: *Tried Lazy, Eager and Explicit loading methods.*

Answer (score 0):

Rename the **DocId** property in your Comment class to **DocumentId** - when using CodeFirst approach you have to be careful about these namings.

LazyLoading set to true should normally do the trick. Try setting it and also include the navigation property in your call:

```
_db.Document.Include("Comment").ToList
```

PS: It is a good convention to use plural names for your tables and dbsets

Comment: *Tried Lazy, Eager and Explicit loading methods.*

Comment: look at the first part of my answer - it is possible that EF cannot recognize your foreign key. That why you should either rename it or decorate it with the proper attribute.

Comment: It's mapped properly. By the way, it's not my code.