# Entity Framework CodeFirst: Sharing entity between other entities

Tags: entity-framework

I'm sharing one entity between other entities with selector property.
Code First codes are :

```
public enum ContentTypes : byte
{
    EntityA = 0,
    EntityB = 1
}

public class SharedContent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ContentTypes ContentType { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class EntityA
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ContentId")]
    public virtual SharedContent Content { get; set; }
    public int ContentId { get; set; }
}

public class EntityB
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ContentId")]
    public virtual SharedContent Content { get; set; }
    public int ContentId { get; set; }
}
```

After executing below codes to get entityA from database entity framework fills all properties except entityA.Content! Whats wrong? What I need to get entityA with Content property?

```
var entityA = context.EntityA.Include(e => e.Content).ToList();
```

Comment: try using '[key]'attributes for Id

Comment: Thanks but I'm already using key attribute. I will update sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake! In original code I'm creating content in constructor.
For detailed explanation follow the link...

[EF codefirst : whether initialize navigation properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20757594/ef-codefirst-whether-initialize-navigation-properties)