# Entity Framework One To Many Relationship mapping foreignkey causing null on navigation properties

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first, foreign-keys

I'm trying to build relationship while wanted to specify child and parent tables foreign key in addition to navigation property,  model looks like this

```
public class Parent
{
    public Parent()
    {
        this.Childern = new HashSet<Child>();
    }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    //public Guid Child_Id { get; set; } 

    public ICollection<Child> Childern { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public Child()
    {
        this.Parent = new Parent();
    }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Guid Parent_Id { get; set; }
    public Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

With only above model when i build and run project, i get expected results on navigation properties as navigation properties are populated with expected data.
But i get additional un-wanted column in database as below

```
Id
Name
Parent_Id
Parent_Id1 (FK)
```

I further configured relationship in OnModelCreating like below

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Child>()
    .HasRequired(p => p.Parent)
    .WithMany(p => p.Childern)
    .HasForeignKey(k => k.Parent_Id);
```

This time I got desired result on table structure now table looks like this

```
Id
Name
Parent_Id (FK)
```

But I'm getting null on navigation properties, please note that I'm trying **Eagerly Loading**

```
    public static void TestParent()
    {
        using (var context = new ILDBContext())
        {
            var parents = context.Parents
                .Include(p => p.Childern)
                .ToList();

            foreach (var parent in parents)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Parent: {0} Childern: {1}", parent.Name, parent.Childern.Count());
                foreach (var child in parent.Childern)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Child: {0}", child.Name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In addition I will be thankful if anyone can advise how should i configure relationship if i need FK in both models like, Parent_Id and Child_Id
Thanks.

Comment: Try marking your collection virtual and don't new it up. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20757594/ef-codefirst-whether-initialize-navigation-properties

Comment: I did try virtual but it does't work, there is something wrong with my relationship statement in OnModelCreating, because without this i get results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `Parent` assignment in your `Child` constructor:

```
public Child()
{
    this.Parent = new Parent();
}
```

has to be

```
public Child() {}
```

or you don't define it at all. For the `ICollection<Child>` in your `Parent` it doesn't really make a difference.

Comment: Thanks it works, can you please explain.  Why it preventing loading navigation properties? Thanks.

Comment: In the constructor you are immediately assigning another parent (empty one) to the navigation property. EF doesn't overwrite the behavior in constructor