# Eager loading not working when lazyloading is false

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-5, lazy-loading, eager-loading

I have a database-first application, with entities `Promotion` and `Product`, and the navigation property `Promotion.Products`. There are other navigation properties on Promotion. I want to ignore these other navigation properties in one of my methods, and load only the promotions, each with a collection of products (code below is simplified).

If I use lazy loading:

```
// Lazy Loading true by default
// ctx.ObjectContext.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
var data = from p in ctx.ObjectContext.Promotions select p;
```

data.First().Products contains 1 Product.

If I use eager loading:

```
ctx.ObjectContext.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
var data = from p in ctx.ObjectContext.Promotions.Include(p => p.Products)
           select p;
```

data.First().Products is empty.

I have used eager loading elsewhere with success. I don't know why it isn't working for me here.

I realize that I can simply use linq joins to get the desired result, but this will complicate my class and cause some duplicated code. I can also force it using:

```
ctx.ObjectContext.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
var data = from p in ctx.ObjectContext.Promotions
           select new {
               Promo = p,
               Products = p.Products
          };
```

which gives 1 item in `data.First().Promo.Products` or `data.First().Products`, but I'd rather do it "by the book".

**Entity Code**

```
    public static Promotion CreatePromotion(global::System.Int32 id, ...)
    {
        Promotion promotion = new Promotion();
        promotion.Id = id;
        ...
        return promotion;
    }
```

...

```
    [XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    [SoapIgnoreAttribute()]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    [EdmRelationshipNavigationPropertyAttribute("MyDataModel", "PromotionsProducts", "Product")]
    public EntityCollection<Product> Products
    {
        get
        {
            return ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.GetRelatedCollection<Product>("MyDataModel.PromotionsProducts", "Product");
        }
        set
        {
            if ((value != null))
            {
                ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.InitializeRelatedCollection<Product>("MyDataModel.PromotionsProducts", "Product", value);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: There has to be something else going on here because I tested this locally and it works fine with `LazyLoadingEnabled=false` and `Include(p => p.Products)` you need to check the rest of the code.

Comment: I have a strong suspicion of what's going on here, but I really need to see the full class definitions.

Comment: @GertArnold I'll try to get that but will need to trim it down a little. In the meantime, tell me your suspicion and I can run some tests.

Comment: OK, I'm particularly interested in the constructors. It could be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20773057/861716).

Comment: It's database-first, so my entities are auto generated, therefore there is no Promotion constructor. There is a CreatePromotion Factory Method. I've posted that above along with The PromotionsProducts Navigation property. Maybe my foreign keys are off.

Comment: Just checked my database schema and I think the FKs are correct. There is a linker table PromotionsProducts, which EF presents as the 2 navigation properties Promotion.Products and Product.Promotions.