# EF 6 Relationship: One or more validation errors were detected during model generation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-relationship

I've been pulling my hair out trying to figure out what I thought would be a relatively simple relationship mapping (one to many).

Let's go over what I have in the models:

**ContentExternalLink**

```
public class ContentExternalLink
{
    public ContentExternalLink()
    {
        ContentTagAssignments = new List<ContentTagAssignment>();
    }

    [Key]
    public string LinkId { get; set; }
    public string LinkTypeId { get; set; }
    public string LinkTitle { get; set; }
    public string LinkUrl { get; set; }
    public string LinkSource { get; set; }
    public string LinkPhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime LinkDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime LinkCreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime LinkModifiedDate { get; set; }
    [ScriptIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<ContentTagAssignment> ContentTagAssignments { get; set; }
}
```

**ContentTagAssignmnent**

```
public class ContentTagAssignment
{
    public ContentTagAssignment()
    {
        this.ContentExternalLink = new ContentExternalLink();
    }

    [Key]
    public string TagId { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public string ArticleId { get; set; }
    public bool IsPrimary { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    [ScriptIgnore]
    public virtual ContentExternalLink ContentExternalLink { get; set; }
}
```

Now into the mapping:

**ContentExternalLinkMap**

```
public class ContentExternalLinkMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<ContentExternalLink>
{
    public ContentExternalLinkMap()
    {
        this.ToTable("content_external_link", "dbo");

        this.HasKey(c => c.LinkId);

        this.Property(c => c.LinkId).HasColumnName("link_id");
        this.Property(c => c.LinkTypeId).HasColumnName("link_type_id");
        this.Property(c => c.LinkTitle).HasColumnName("link_title");
        this.Property(c => c.LinkUrl).HasColumnName("link_url");
        this.Property(c => c.LinkSource).HasColumnName("link_source");
        this.Property(c => c.LinkPhoneNumber).HasColumnName("link_phone_number");
        this.Property(c => c.LinkDate).HasColumnName("link_date");
        this.Property(c => c.LinkCreatedDate).HasColumnName("link_created_date");
        this.Property(c => c.LinkModifiedDate).HasColumnName("link_modified_date");
    }
}
```

**ContentTagAssignmnetMap**

```
public class ContentTagAssignmentMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<ContentTagAssignment>
{
    public ContentTagAssignmentMap()
    {
        this.ToTable("content_tag_assignment", "dbo");

        this.HasKey(t => new {t.TagId, t.ArticleId});

        this.Property(t => t.TagId).HasColumnName("tag_id");
        this.Property(t => t.ArticleId).HasColumnName("article_id");
        this.Property(t => t.IsPrimary).HasColumnName("is_primary_tag");
        this.Property(t => t.CreatedDate).HasColumnName("created_date");


        this.HasOptional(t => t.ContentExternalLink)
            .WithMany(t => t.ContentTagAssignments)
            .HasForeignKey(t => new {t.TagId, t.ArticleId});
    }
}
```

The relation is definitely on the weird side as in LinkId would match up with ArticleId in ContentTagAssignment.

I've tried the following in ContentTagAssignmentMap:

```
    //this.HasOptional(t => t.ContentExternalLink)
//    .WithMany(t => t.ContentTagAssignments)
//    .HasForeignKey(t => t.ContentExternalLink);

this.HasOptional(x => x.ContentExternalLink)
    .WithMany(x=>x.ContentTagAssignments)
    .Map(x => x.MapKey("LinkId").HasColumnAnnotation("LinkId","ArticleId",null));

//this.Map(m =>
//    {
//        m.Properties(x => x.ArticleId);
//        m.ToTable("content_tag_assignment");
//    })
//    .Map(p =>
//    {
//        p.Properties(x => x.ContentExternalLink.LinkId);
//        p.ToTable("ContentExternalLink");
//    });
```

The commented relations doesn't work. The one that works (in that it doesn't fail on initial page load). However, when I try to access the List from the ContentExternalLink, I get the following error: {"Invalid column name 'LinkId'.\r\nInvalid column name 'LinkId'."}

So I'm even more lost...

**Question**

Basically, not every ContentExternalLink will have a tag assignment to it. But, if there are ContentTagAssignments to a ContentExternalLink, I should be able to get a list of them. Also, the TagId and ArticleId are strings (guids).

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: Both models you have shown are the same (`ContentTagAssignmnent`) :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke doh! Thanks for letting me know, I've updated the ContentExternalLink model with the real model.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20757594/861716

Comment: @GertArnold I'm not sure how that post applies to my question. I have updated my post with more information.

Comment: Look at your `ContentTagAssignment` constructor.

Comment: Tried: public virtual ContentExternalLink ContentExternalLink
        {
            get
            {
                return this._contentExternalLink ?? (this._contentExternalLink = new ContentExternalLink());
            }
        }

But it still doesn't work.

Comment: Shouldn't the TagAssignment class just have the LinkId instead of a Link object?  After all, the one-to-many is just a foreign key (the guid of the one) in the many table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the comments from [ivan stoev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5202563/ivan-stoev), i see that the unique mistake here is setting optional when the foreign key is also a primary key (`not nullable`)

So the mapping will be:

```
public class ContentTagAssignmentMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<ContentTagAssignment>
{
    public ContentTagAssignmentMap()
    {
        this.ToTable("content_tag_assignment", "dbo");

        this.HasKey(t => new { t.TagId, t.ArticleId });

        this.Property(t => t.TagId).HasColumnName("tag_id");
        this.Property(t => t.ArticleId).HasColumnName("article_id");
        this.Property(t => t.IsPrimary).HasColumnName("is_primary_tag");
        this.Property(t => t.CreatedDate).HasColumnName("created_date");


        this.HasRequired(t => t.ContentExternalLink)
            .WithMany(t => t.ContentTagAssignments)
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.ArticleId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

Below is a working example with your model:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var ctx = new Context();
        ctx.Database.Delete();
        ctx.Database.CreateIfNotExists();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context():base ("Teste")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<ContentExternalLink> ContentExternalLinks { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ContentTagAssignment> ContentTagAssignments { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ContentExternalLinkMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ContentTagAssignmentMap());

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

}

public class ContentExternalLink
{
    public ContentExternalLink()
    {
        ContentTagAssignments = new List<ContentTagAssignment>();
    }

    [Key]
    public string LinkId { get; set; }
    public string LinkTypeId { get; set; }
    public string LinkTitle { get; set; }
    public string LinkUrl { get; set; }
    public string LinkSource { get; set; }
    public string LinkPhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime LinkDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime LinkCreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime LinkModifiedDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ContentTagAssignment> ContentTagAssignments { get; set; }
}

public class ContentTagAssignment
{
    public ContentTagAssignment()
    {
        this.ContentExternalLink = new ContentExternalLink();
    }

    [Key]
    public string TagId { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public string ArticleId { get; set; }
    public bool IsPrimary { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ContentExternalLink ContentExternalLink { get; set; }
}

public class ContentExternalLinkMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<ContentExternalLink>
{
    public ContentExternalLinkMap()
    {
        this.ToTable("content_external_link", "dbo");

        this.HasKey(c => c.LinkId);

        this.Property(c => c.LinkId).HasColumnName("link_id");
        this.Property(c => c.LinkTypeId).HasColumnName("link_type_id");
        this.Property(c => c.LinkTitle).HasColumnName("link_title");
        this.Property(c => c.LinkUrl).HasColumnName("link_url");
        this.Property(c => c.LinkSource).HasColumnName("link_source");
        this.Property(c => c.LinkPhoneNumber).HasColumnName("link_phone_number");
        this.Property(c => c.LinkDate).HasColumnName("link_date");
        this.Property(c => c.LinkCreatedDate).HasColumnName("link_created_date");
        this.Property(c => c.LinkModifiedDate).HasColumnName("link_modified_date");
    }
}

public class ContentTagAssignmentMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<ContentTagAssignment>
{
    public ContentTagAssignmentMap()
    {
        this.ToTable("content_tag_assignment", "dbo");

        this.HasKey(t => new { t.TagId, t.ArticleId });

        this.Property(t => t.TagId).HasColumnName("tag_id");
        this.Property(t => t.ArticleId).HasColumnName("article_id");
        this.Property(t => t.IsPrimary).HasColumnName("is_primary_tag");
        this.Property(t => t.CreatedDate).HasColumnName("created_date");


        this.HasRequired(t => t.ContentExternalLink)
            .WithMany(t => t.ContentTagAssignments)
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.ArticleId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

Here is the result from the code above:

[image: Created Tables]

Comment: Sorry, I reverted back the proposed change. The FK is always at the `many` side, so it cannot be the `LinkId`.

Comment: Its the key on the optional side that references the many side that you'll use. You need the FK on ContentTagAssignment that references ContentExternalLink, which is LinkId

Comment: Correct. But there is no `LinkId` property in the OP provided `ContentTagAssignment` entity, and according to the OP explanation, *LinkId would match up with ArticleId in ContentTagAssignment*, so my assumption is based on that statement (and is mentioned in the answer).

Comment: Did not see that ArticleId would match LinkId. My mistake, sorry

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues with your entity model/implementation.

Let start with the simlpler (mentioned in the [Gert Arnold's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39958424/ef-6-relationship-one-or-more-validation-errors-were-detected-during-model-gene#comment67236635_39958424)). As a rule of thumb, you should never initialize a single navigation property inside the constructor (or any other place internally) because that would break the EF lazy loading behavior.

Shortly, simply remove

`this.ContentExternalLink = new ContentExternalLink();`

line from the `ContentTagAssignment` class constructor.

Now the main issue. EF6 supports only FK (foreign key) relationships that refer to the PK (primary key) of the principal end. Which means you cannot use a composite key (`TagId, ArticleId`) in the `ContentTagAssignment` entity to refer to a single PK (`LinkId`) of the `ContentExternalLink` entity as you are trying to set with the `HasForeignKey(t => new {t.TagId, t.ArticleId})` call. The fact that these two columns form the PK of the dependent end (`ContentTagAssignment`) is irrelevant for the relationship. There is no other choice - you have to pick one of the two fields. And according to *LinkId would match up with ArticleId in ContentTagAssignment*, that should be the `ArticleId` field.

If my guess is correct, simply replace

```
this.HasOptional(t => t.ContentExternalLink)
    .WithMany(t => t.ContentTagAssignments)
    .HasForeignKey(t => new {t.TagId, t.ArticleId});
```

with

```
this.HasRequired(t => t.ContentExternalLink)
    .WithMany(t => t.ContentTagAssignments)
    .HasForeignKey(t => t.ArticleId);
```

and that (along with the constructor modification) should solve the issue.

Note that I also changed `HasOptional` to `HasRequired` because the `ArticleId` field is part of the PK, hence will not allow `null` values anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that you are trying to have a foreign key without indicating the correct join.

What you need to do is add a LinkId field to ContentTagAssignment which is the actual foreign key you should be using and join to that:

```
this.HasOptional(t => t.ContentExternalLink)
.WithMany(t => t.ContentTagAssignments)
.HasForeignKey(t => t.LinkId);
```

The reason is that you are telling it to go find a key (tagId, ArticleId) that just doesn't exist in ContentExternalLink.