# A Different way to add entities using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, code-first

I have following classes in my model:

```
public class Country
{
    [Key]
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<State> States { get; set; }
}

public class State
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Country Country { get; set; }
}
```

I know how to add a new Country and a new State using DbConext by coding like:

```
Country country = new Country() { Code = "USA", Name = "United States" };
State state = new State() { Code = "CA", Name = "California", Country = country };
db.Countries.Add(country);
db.States.Add(state);
db.SaveChanges();

// db is the instance of DbContext.
```

I was trying to do that in another way by creating only country and then add State to it's collection property:

```
Country country = new Country() { Code = "USA", Name = "United States" };
country.States.Add(new State() { Code = "CA", Name = "California" });
```

But I noticed that `country.States` is null.

My questions are:

1. How should I initialize `country.States` so I can add a new State to that collection.
2. Does doing it using the second method make any sense? (if it is feasible)

Comment: property country.States exists and is null. What do you mean by saying it does not exists

Comment: Oh, it was a typo. I add the "s" now

Comment: `country.States = new List<State>();` I'm not sure what the confusion is?

Comment: @DavidG, Thanks for comment. can you answer the second part of the question? does it matter if I use the first method or the second?

Comment: I don't think so, best way to check is to see what SQL is being run though.

Comment: Both questions are opninion-based. It really doesn't matter which method you use for initializing the collection or associating the entities. Maybe the best we can say is: adhere to your own conventions.

Comment: Thank you all. I tried what @DavidG said and it worked.

Comment: Maybe one to keep in mind: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20757594/861716.

Comment: Just to add that the variation of the second way allows you to use "one-liners" like `db.Countries.Add(new Country { Code = "USA", Name = "United States", States = new List<State> { new State { Code = "CA", Name = "California" } } });`

Comment: Good point. Thank you