# How to transfer model to editpage from Data Base?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My input model consists of NewForm in which many fields

```
public class NewForm
    {
         [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string HeadForm { get; set; }

        public List<Field> Fields { get; set; }   
    }

    public class Field
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public bool Check { get; set; }
        public string HeadField { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to take values from the base and edit them, but Model.Fields.Count throw exception. Although the string "HeadForm" is displayed. Lists are not displayed.
EditPage:

```
@model EditFormApplication.Models.NewForm

@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.HeadForm)
    <h5>Fields:</h5><br>
        @for ( var i = 0; i< Model.Fields.Count; i++) {
          @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Fields[i].HeadField)                     
          @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Fields[i].Check)
        }
        <input type="button" value="Add Field" onclick="addField(this);">
        <input type="submit"value="Save">
}
```

For example, I am typing data by ID = 3.
Controller:

```
 public ActionResult CreateForm(NewForm model)
    {
        using (NewFormContext db = new NewFormContext())
        {
           db.NewForms.Add(model);
           db.SaveChanges();
           return RedirectToAction("Edit");
         }
     }

  public ActionResult Edit()
    {
        using (NewFormContext db = new NewFormContext()) { 
            var model = db.NewForms.Find(3);

        return this.View(model);
    }
    }
```

used Code First and one to many

Comment: Because you might have `Model.Fields` null that why you are getting error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like `Model.Fields` property still contain null when `db.NewForms.Find()` is executed to assign the model you want to return into view, indicating that EF doesn't create dependent collection yet. As far as I know you should add collection instance definition inside parameterless constructor of entity class:

```
public class NewForm
{
    public NewForm()
    {
        // instantiate list here
        Fields = new List<Field>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string HeadForm { get; set; }

    public List<Field> Fields { get; set; }   
}
```

Or if you're using lazy loading, mark the property as `virtual` to let EF instantiate the collection while necessary:

```
public virtual List<Field> Fields { get; set; }
```

Related issue:

[EF codefirst : Should I initialize navigation properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20757594/ef-codefirst-should-i-initialize-navigation-properties)