# Eager loading with include method does not return data from collection

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I wanted to eager load a collection but it does not returns any data

I have tried nothing

//here is my controller

```
var accountGroup = await db.AccountGroups.Include(a=>a.AccountGroupTypes)
.Include(a=>a.AccountPrimaryGroups).ToListAsync();
```

//here is my model

```
public int? Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public int AccountGroupTypeId { get; set; }
public ICollection<AccountGroupType> AccountGroupTypes { get; set; }

public int AccountPrimaryGroupId { get; set; }
public ICollection<AccountPrimaryGroup> AccountPrimaryGroups { get; set; }

public DateTime CreationDateUtcNow{ get; set; }
```

It returns AccountGroupData but It does not return AccountGroupTypes and AccountPrimaryGroup data

Comment: [Log the SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/logging-and-interception) and run it against your database.

Answer (score 0):

Mark your `AccountGroupTypes` and `AccountPrimaryGroups` as virtual properties and be sure that you have a parameterless constructor which is initializing those properties.

```
public int? Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public int AccountGroupTypeId { get; set; }
public vitual ICollection<AccountGroupType> AccountGroupTypes { get; set; }
public int AccountPrimaryGroupId { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<AccountPrimaryGroup> AccountPrimaryGroups { get; set; }
public DateTime CreationDateUtcNow{ get; set; }

public AccountGroup()
{
    this.AccountGroupTypes = new HashSet<AccountGroupType>();
    this.AccountPrimaryGroups = new HashSet<AccountPrimaryGroups>();
}
```

Comment: Virtual is for lazy loading. You also don't need to `new` up the collections. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20757594/ef-codefirst-should-i-initialize-navigation-properties).