# EF Core: detached lazy-loading navigation entity. Why?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have the following model:

```
public partial class Device
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Tablet Tablet { get; set; }
```

where `Tablet` is the following:

```
public class Tablet
{
    public string TabletId { get; set; }

    public int DeviceId { get; set; }
    public virtual Device Device { get; set; }

    private ICollection<TabletTransferRequest> _tabletTransferRequests;
    public virtual ICollection<TabletTransferRequest> TabletTransferRequests { get => _tabletTransferRequests ?? (_tabletTransferRequests = new List<TabletTransferRequest>()); protected set => _tabletTransferRequests = value; }
}
```

and the mapping class:

```
public class TabletMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Tablet>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Tablet> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable(nameof(Tablet));
        builder.HasKey(p => p.TabletId);

        builder.HasOne(p => p.Device)
            .WithOne(o => o.Tablet)
            .HasForeignKey<Tablet>(p => p.DeviceId)
            .IsRequired()
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
            ;
    }
}
```

DTO classes:

```
public class DeviceDisplayDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public TabletPartDto Tablet { get; set; }
}

public class TabletPartDto
{
    public string TabletId { get; set; }
    public List<TabletTransferRequestElementDto> TabletTransferRequests { get; set; }
}


public class TabletTransferRequestElementDto : DeviceRequestElementAbstractDto
{
    public string TabletId { get; set; }
    public int DeviceId { get; set; }
}
```

when I try to do the following

```
        var query = _context.Devices.Include(d => d.Tablet).ThenInclude(d => d.TabletTransferRequests);
        var devices = new PagedList<DeviceDisplayDto>(query.ProjectTo<DeviceDisplayDto>(_mapperConfig), pageIndex, pageSize);
```

I got the following:

> Error generated for warning
> 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DetachedLazyLoadingWarning:
> An attempt was made to lazy-load navigation property
> 'TabletTransferRequests' on detached entity of type 'TabletProxy'.
> Lazy-loading is not supported for detached entities or entities that
> are loaded with 'AsNoTracking()'.'. This exception can be suppressed
> or logged by passing event ID 'CoreEventId.DetachedLazyLoadingWarning'
> to the 'ConfigureWarnings' method in 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' or
> 'AddDbContext'.

why it's detached?

Comment: To my knowledge, this happens when you use AsNoTracking() in your query, but your posted code doesn't show that. https://forums.asp.net/t/2167300.aspx?Problem+to+use+AsNoTracking+query+in+master+detail+entities+

Comment: Does this help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20757594/ef-codefirst-should-i-initialize-navigation-properties
QUOTE: "In EF-core 3, initializing a reference navigation property prevents Include from working properly."

Comment: Also potentially relevant to your motivation to instantiate in get ... Null coalesce assignment is also handy for dealing with potentially empty collections:
(col ??= new col()).Add()  will allow you to instantiate null collection and add in one line.  If col not null, then use it, else instantiate it and use it.

Comment: This should not happen when projecting to dtos. (and `Include` / `ThenInclude` are not needed). With that in mind, which line generates the exception (can we see the exception stack trace)? Also can we see the missing classes (`TabletTransferRequest`, `DeviceRequestElementAbstractDto`) and AutoMapper mappings?

Answer (score 0):

Is the error occurring on the `var devices = new PagedList(...)` or later, such as when the controller method completes? I don't recognize that PagedList implementation, but from what you've typed that rendition appears to be initializing with `IQueryable<T>` rather than a static collection `IList<T>` which may be an issue if the `PagedList` ends up attempting to resolve paging from the `IQueryable` after an initial load.

Normally PagedList would utilize a `ToPagedList(page, pageSize)` method when working with `IQueryable` which would trigger a one-off load of a Page. If written as a class initialized with an `IQueryable`, a data retrieval query could be non-fillable if queried after the DbContext is disposed.