# Use Id from a lookup table, to create a new database entry

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core, entity-relationship

To create a `new BaseClass` I only want to assign the Id's `C2NumberId` and `C1NumberId`.

Data structure:

```
[Table("BaseClass")]
public class BaseClass
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("C1")]
    public int C1NumberId { get; set; }
    public virtual C1 C1 { get; set; }


    public BaseClass()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        C1 = new C1();
    }
}


[Table("C1")]
public class C1
{
    [Key]
    public int C1NumberId { get; set; }
    public string C1Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("C2")]
    public int C2NumberId { get; set; }
    public virtual C2 C2 { get; set; }


    public C1()
    {
        C2 = new C2();
    }

}

[Table("C2")]
public class C2
{
    [Key]
    public int C2NumberId { get; set; }
    public string C2Name { get; set; }
}
```

Database schema:

[image: here]

Access DBContext:

```
using (XDBTestingContext db = new XDBTestingContext())
{ 
    BaseClass bc = new BaseClass();

    bc.C1NumberId = 1;// I already have that Id, table is just for look up 
    bc.SomeProperty = "dksal";

    bc.C1.C1NumberId = 1; // I already have that Id, table is just for look up 
    bc.C1.C2.C2NumberId = 1; // I already have that Id, table is just for look up 

    db.BaseClass.Add(bc);
    //db.BaseClass.Entry(bc).State = EntityState.Detached;
    //db.BaseClass.Entry(bc).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Error:

> 'The instance of entity type 'C2' cannot be tracked because another
> instance with the same key value for {'C2NumberId'} is already being
> tracked.  When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one
> entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using

I have read that I have to change the state (take a  look at my comments), but it does not seem to work.
Actually I just want to assign the existing Id to `C2NumberId` or `C1NumberId`, without loading the entire object.

How should it look the right way?

Comment: EF Core has limitation for navigation properties. https://stackoverflow.com/a/20773057/10646316

Comment: Remove `C1 = new C1();` from the constructor. If you already have the classes you shouldn't create new instances of them. And, as said, this should never be done in constructors. All you need is `bc.C1NumberId = 1`.