# Problem with Include() EntityFramework Core with blazor server side

Tags: sql, entity-framework-core

I have a problem with Include() using Entity Framework.
I have two models:

```
public class Project
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Project Title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        // Some other properties


        public int ProjectPropertyId { get; set; }
        public ProjectProperty ProjectProperty { get; set; } = new ProjectProperty();

    }
```

and the other table:

```
public class ProjectProperty
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Published")]
        public bool Published { get; set; } = false;
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Code Available")]
        public bool CodeAvailable { get; set; } = false;
    }
```

When I save a new entity with those properties, No problem.
When I want to retrieve, here the problem is.
I can get the Project list, but it doesn't include the Project property Entity.
This is the code to get the list:

```
public async Task<List<Project>> GetProjects()
        {
            return await _context.Project.Include(p => p.ProjectProperty).ToListAsync();
        }
```

On the break point I get this:

[image]

I can't get that entity with Include()
but in the database:

[image]

I know I did a stupid mistake, but I can't figure it out.
any help will be appreciated thank you.

Comment: Remove initialization of the reference navigation property `= new ProjectProperty();`. There are many posts on SO explaining why you shouldn't do that, and of course the main reason is that it prevents correct eager/lazy/explicit loading.

Comment: I just figured it out right now. Thank you for your help. It work's now.

Comment: @IvanStoev Would you post the comment as an answer so I can mark it as answered.

Comment: This is one of those posts: [EF codefirst : Should I initialize navigation properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20757594/ef-codefirst-should-i-initialize-navigation-properties)

Comment: @Gert Thank you, that's my preferred duplicate target for this, I should keep the link somewhere. Even it's been quite time since then, it still applies.

Comment: @Ivan Sure :) I try to keep it up-to-date every now and then.