# Problem with many to many query generated by Entity framework core

Tags: entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

i have many to many relationship beetwen 6 tables
Associative model:

```
  public class Product
{

   public int? GameId { get; set; }
 
    public Game Game { get; set; } = new Game();

    public int? PlatformId { get; set; }

    public Platform Platform { get; set; } = new Platform();

    public int? ManufactureId { get; set; }
 
    public Manufacture Manufacture { get; set; } = new Manufacture();

    public int? LocalizationId { get; set; }

    public Localization Localization { get; set; } = new Localization();

    public int? GenreId { get; set; }
  
    public Genre Genre { get; set; } = new Genre();

    public int? RegionrestrictId { get; set; }
  
    public Country RegionRestrict { get; set; } = new Country();



}
```

main related model:

```
 public class Game
{
    public int Id { get; }

 
    public string Titleofgame { get; set; }


    public string Description { get; set; }


    public DateTime DateRelese { get; set; }

    public List<Manufacture> Manufactures { get; set; } = new List<Manufacture>();


    public  List<Product> Products { get; set; } = new List<Product>();

    public int? Idseriesofgame { get; set; }

    public Serie Series { get; set; }


    public int? Idpublication { get; set; }

    public Publication Publication { get; set; }



    public List<Platform> Platforms { get; set; } = new List<Platform>();





 
    public List<Localization> Localizations { get; set; } = new List<Localization>();


   
    public List<Genre> Genres { get; set; } = new List<Genre>();

   
    public List<Country> RegionRestricts { get; set; } = new List<Country>();


 
  
}
```

and one of the tables wicht related with "Game":

```
  public class Genre
{
    public int Id { get;  }

    [Display(Name ="Жанр")]

    public string Titleofgenre { get; set; }
 
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; } = new List<Product>();

    public List<Game> Games { get; set; } = new List<Game>();
}
```

(other tables are the same)and there is a table in Mysql "Products":
[image]
and also some data:
[image]

when i try to get data from code:

```
 IEnumerable<Product> query = _context.Products.Include(d => d.Game).ThenInclude(d=>d.Genres).Include(d=>d.Game.Manufactures).Include(d=>d.Game.Platforms).Include(d=>d.Game.Localizations).Include(d=>d.Game.RegionRestricts).Include(d => d.Genre).Include(d => d.Localization).Include(d => d.Platform).Include(d => d.RegionRestrict).Include(d => d.Manufacture).ToList();
```

Entity framework generate such a query:

```
 SELECT `p`.`gameid`, `p`.`genreid`, `p`.`localizationid`, `p`.`manufactureid`, `p`.`platformid`, `p`.`regionrestrictid`, `g`.`id`, `g`.`daterelese`, `g`.`description`, `g`.`idpublication`, `g`.`idseriesofgame`, `g`.`titleofgame`, `g0`.`id`, `g0`.`titleofgenre`, `l`.`id`, `l`.`titleoflocalization`, `p0`.`id`, `p0`.`titleofplatform`, `c`.`id`, `c`.`titleofcountry`, `m`.`id`, `m`.`titleofmanufactures`
  FROM `Products` AS `p`
  INNER JOIN `games` AS `g` ON `p`.`gameid` = `g`.`id`
  INNER JOIN `genres` AS `g0` ON `p`.`genreid` = `g0`.`id`
  INNER JOIN `localizations` AS `l` ON `p`.`localizationid` = `l`.`id`
  INNER JOIN `platforms` AS `p0` ON `p`.`platformid` = `p0`.`id`
  INNER JOIN `countries` AS `c` ON `p`.`regionrestrictid` = `c`.`id`
  INNER JOIN `manufactures` AS `m` ON `p`.`manufactureid` = `m`.`id`
```

therefore i'm getting only 4 of 11 elements:
[image]

also there is configuration in fluent api:

```
        modelBuilder
      .Entity<Game>()
      .HasMany(c => c.Localizations)
      .WithMany(s => s.Games)
      .UsingEntity<Product>(
         j =>
          j.HasOne(pt => pt.Localization)
          .WithMany(t => t.Products)
          .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.LocalizationId),
      j =>
          j.HasOne(pt => pt.Game)
          .WithMany(p => p.Products)
          .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.GameId),


      j =>
      {

          j.HasKey(t => new { t.GameId, t.ManufactureId, t.GenreId, t.PlatformId, t.RegionrestrictId });
          j.ToTable("Products");
      }
  );

        modelBuilder
          .Entity<Game>()
          .HasMany(c => c.Platforms)
          .WithMany(s => s.Games)
          .UsingEntity<Product>(
             j =>
              j.HasOne(pt => pt.Platform)
              .WithMany(t => t.Products)
              .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.PlatformId),
          j =>
              j.HasOne(pt => pt.Game)
              .WithMany(p => p.Products)
              .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.GameId),


          j =>
          {

              j.HasKey(t => new { t.GameId, t.ManufactureId, t.GenreId, t.PlatformId, t.RegionrestrictId });
              j.ToTable("Products");
          }
      );


        modelBuilder
          .Entity<Game>()
          .HasMany(c => c.Genres)
          .WithMany(s => s.Games)
          .UsingEntity<Product>(
             j =>
              j.HasOne(pt => pt.Genre)
              .WithMany(t => t.Products)
              .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.GenreId),
          j =>
              j.HasOne(pt => pt.Game)
              .WithMany(p => p.Products)
              .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.GameId),


          j =>
          {

              j.HasKey(t => new { t.GameId, t.ManufactureId, t.GenreId, t.PlatformId, t.RegionrestrictId });
              j.ToTable("Products");
          }
      );


        modelBuilder
            .Entity<Game>()
            .HasMany(c => c.RegionRestricts)
            .WithMany(s => s.Games)
            .UsingEntity<Product>(
               j =>
                j.HasOne(pt => pt.RegionRestrict)
                .WithMany(t => t.Products)
                .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.RegionrestrictId),
            j =>
                j.HasOne(pt => pt.Game)
                .WithMany(p => p.Products)
                .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.GameId),


            j =>
            {

                j.HasKey(t => new { t.GameId, t.ManufactureId, t.GenreId, t.PlatformId, t.RegionrestrictId });
                j.ToTable("Products");
            }
        );



        modelBuilder.Entity<Game>()
   .HasOne(a => a.Series)
   .WithMany(a => a.Games)
   .HasForeignKey(c => c.Idseriesofgame);

        modelBuilder
            .Entity<Game>()
            .HasMany(c => c.Manufactures)
            .WithMany(s => s.Games)
            .UsingEntity<Product>(
               j =>
                j.HasOne(pt => pt.Manufacture)
                .WithMany(t => t.Products)
                .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.ManufactureId),
            j =>
                j.HasOne(pt => pt.Game)
                .WithMany(p => p.Products)
                .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.GameId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade),



            j =>
            {

                j.HasKey(t => new { t.GameId, t.ManufactureId, t.GenreId, t.PlatformId, t.RegionrestrictId });
                j.ToTable("Products");
            }
        );




        modelBuilder.Entity<Game>().HasMany(d => d.Products).WithOne(d => d.Game).HasForeignKey(d => d.GameId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

       
        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
            .HasOne(bc => bc.Game)
            .WithMany(b => b.Products)
            .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.GameId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
            .HasOne(bc => bc.RegionRestrict)
            .WithMany(b => b.Products)
            .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.RegionrestrictId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
      .HasOne(bc => bc.Genre)
      .WithMany(b => b.Products)
      .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.GenreId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
      .HasOne(bc => bc.Localization)
      .WithMany(b => b.Products)
      .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.LocalizationId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
      .HasOne(bc => bc.Manufacture)
      .WithMany(b => b.Products)
      .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.ManufactureId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
      .HasOne(bc => bc.Platform)
      .WithMany(b => b.Products)
      .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.PlatformId);
modelBuilder.Entity<Game>().HasKey(p => p.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Genre>().HasKey(p => p.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Localization>().HasKey(p => p.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Manufacture>().HasKey(p => p.Id);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Platform>().HasKey(p => p.Id);
     modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
      .HasKey(bc =>  bc.GameId );
```

its suppose to be left join if i want to get all data, but i dont know how to do it.

Comment: The screenshot display 11 games and EF query ask products (that return 4). It's different tables with different row count.

Comment: @vernou mb i'm wrong, but  i showed products table, not games table(written on top)

Comment: Is database table created from the code, or vice versa? All these nullable fields inside composite PK look suspicious. I don't think EF Core supports such configuration - most likely it assumes all these are non nullable, hence the inner joins.

Comment: Btw, side note - do not initialize reference navigation properties with `new` because it will cause other issues (I was almost going to close the question as duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20757594/ef-codefirst-should-i-initialize-navigation-properties)

Comment: In the fluent declaration of the primary key of the table product, you miss the column `localizationid`.

Comment: @IvanStoev i use Database-first, and after i had created tables in Mysql, i created models in c# by myself. I've done it by example from:https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframeworkcore/3.6.php

Comment: @vernou I've edited, but it still doesnt work

Comment: @IvanStoev And As you can see on first screenshot, all foreing key are nullabe

Comment: Yes, I see. But that's not what EF Core expects from such model. All EF Core behaviors depend on code model, not the actual database. So if there are discrepancies, you'd get unexpected behaviors.

Comment: @IvanStoev say, EF model need correspond to DB model. If the EF entity's primary key don't correspond the DB table primary key (or unique constraint), then some DB rows can be merged in same EF entity.