# Entity Framework CORE Seeding Joining table

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations, asp.net-core-6.0

I am working on .NET CORE 6 along with EF CORE 7. I need to seed data in joining table but unable to do so and get error.

I am seed `FileTypeId` but not sure why EF core migration throwing error...

`error`

```
The seed entity for entity type 'JobFileType' cannot be added because it has the navigation 'FileType' set. To seed relationships,  add the entity seed to 'JobFileType' and specify the foreign key values {'FileTypeId'}. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the involved property values.
```

`ClassA`

```
public class JobProfile
{
    public JobProfile()
    {
        this.JobFileTypes = new HashSet<JobFileType>();
    }

    public Guid JobProfileId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<JobFileType>? JobFileTypes { get; set; }
}
```

`ClassB`

```
public class FileType
{
    public FileType()
    {
        this.JobFileTypes = new HashSet<JobFileType>();
    }

    public Guid FileTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Extension { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public ICollection<JobFileType>? JobFileTypes { get; set; }
}
```

`Joing Table`

```
 public class JobFileType
{
    public Guid JobFileTypeId { get; set; }
    public Guid JobProfileId { get; set; }
    public JobProfile JobProfile { get; set; } = new JobProfile();
    public Guid FileTypeId { get; set; }
    public FileType FileType { get; set; } = new FileType();
}
```

`Seed Extension`

```
public static class JobFileTypeSeed
{
    public static void Seed(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<JobFileType>()
            .HasData(
                new JobFileType {JobFileTypeId = Guid.Parse("aaa"), JobProfileId = Guid.Parse("ccc"), FileTypeId = Guid.Parse("yyy") },
                new JobFileType { JobFileTypeId = Guid.Parse("bbb"), JobProfileId = Guid.Parse("ccc"), FileTypeId = Guid.Parse("zzz") }
              );
    }
}
```

`config`

```
internal class JobFileTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<JobFileType>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<JobFileType> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("JobFileType", "dbo");

        builder.HasKey(column => column.JobFileTypeId);

        builder
            .HasOne(jobFileType => jobFileType.JobProfile)
            .WithMany(jobProfile => jobProfile.JobFileTypes)
            .HasForeignKey(jobFileType => jobFileType.JobProfileId);

        builder
            .HasOne(jobFileType => jobFileType.FileType)
            .WithMany(fileType => fileType.JobFileTypes)
            .HasForeignKey(jobFileType => jobFileType.FileTypeId);
       
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you have to seed first ```JobProfile``` and ```FileType``` ?

Comment: I wounder if it does makes the difference?

Comment: I'm not completely familiar with that, but whenever I seeding data I approach it this way and I haven't had any problems so far

Comment: I am doing in following sequence 

FileTypeSeed.Seed(modelBuilder);
            JobProfileSeed.Seed(modelBuilder);
            JobFileTypeSeed.Seed(modelBuilder);

Comment: I am seeding joining table `JobFileType` in last after seeding JobProfile and FileType

Comment: Yes, that's what you mean, so you it looks fine for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not much to say about the concrete issue (which btw is not specific to joining entity, but any entity model seeding):

> I am seed `FileTypeId` but not sure why EF core migration throwing error...

as the cause of the issue is included at the beginning of the error message:

> because it has the navigation 'FileType' set.

And your entity has

```cs
public FileType FileType { get; set; } = new FileType();
//                                     ^  ^   ^
//                                     the problem
```

and the same for

```cs
public JobProfile JobProfile { get; set; } = new JobProfile();
```

which will be the next error if you resolve the original.

Remove both navigation property initializers (`= new ...`) and the problem will be gone.

As a general rule, you should *never* initialize *reference* navigation properties because it causes many side effects and/or improper behaviors (not only for seeding, but also eager/lazy/explicit data loading). Initializing *collection* navigation properties is arbitrary, but ok. Only *reference* navigation property initialization must be avoided. For more info, see [EF codefirst : Should I initialize navigation properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20757594/ef-codefirst-should-i-initialize-navigation-properties) - quite old EF topic, but still applies.

If you are trying to resolve NRT warnings (as I guess), initializing with `new` is definitely not a proper way. One reason I don't like NRT is because it is forcing people to use "workarounds" for preventing compiler warnings, which in fact break the primary functionality. Specifically in EF Core, enabling NRT also changes the optional/required attribute of some properties, hence database column types (most noticeable for `string` properties/columns and reference navigations). You could read more about this in the [Working with Nullable Reference Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/nullable-reference-types) topic in the official EF Core documentation, but in general I would just disable NRT for EF entity model classes.

Comment: This is very helpful, and yes it did solve the problem and thanks for explaining all.

Comment: I've noticed initializing navigation properties with 'null!' doesn't bother the data seeding mechanism. So you can use that value to initialize properties if you really want to get rid of null-checking warnings.

Answer (score 1):

The proper order is to set the "master data" first and then try to set the join table, as you would expect.

The defaulting

```
{get;set;} = new Something();
```

Could be the offending declaration, since any instance upon creation will have the relation JobFileType already set