# Updates on n:m Relationship Tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am using the Entity Framework with Library Versions 7.0.14 in a .NET MAUI App with SQLite.

Currently, I am struggeling with Updates on connected Tables. I have 3 different Tables. One of them is a Table "Foods", the second is a Table "SavedMeals" to save different foods in a Meal and the other one is a connection table between "Foods" and "SavedMeals" and the n:m relationship, called "FoodSelection".

I can have several Foods and also the same Foods in a different SavedMeals.

```cs
[Index(nameof(Name), IsUnique = true)]
public class Food
{
    [Key]                                                               // Primary Key will already be indexed in a Table
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int Id { get; set; }


    [Required]
    [Column(Order = 2, TypeName = "TEXT COLLATE NOCASE")]              // Causes the Unique Constraint to ignore case sensitivity 
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 3)]
    public string? Brand { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 4)]
    public double Fats { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 5)]
    public double Carbohydrates { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 6)]
    public double Proteins { get; set; }



    public List<FoodSelection> FoodSelections { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
[Index(nameof(Name), IsUnique = true)]
public class SavedMeal
{
    [Key]                                                               // Primary Key will already be indexed in a Table
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int Id { get; set; }



    [Required]
    [Column(Order = 2, TypeName = "TEXT COLLATE NOCASE")]               // Causes the Unique Constraint to ignore case sensitivity 
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 3)]
    public int MacroNutrientRatio_MaxProteins { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 4)]
    public int MacroNutrientRatio_MaxCarbohydrates { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 5)]
    public int MacroNutrientRatio_MaxFats { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 6)]
    public DateTime LastSavedDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;



    public List<FoodSelection> FoodSelections { get; set; } = new List<FoodSelection>();
}
```

```cs
public class FoodSelection : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Private Variables

    private SavedMeal _savedMeal = new SavedMeal();
    private Food _foodItem = new Food();

    #endregion


    [Key]                                                   // Primary Key will already be indexed in a Table
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    #region SavedMeal

    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public int SavedMealId { get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey(nameof(SavedMealId))]
    public SavedMeal SavedMealItem
    {
        get => _savedMeal;
        set
        {
            if (_savedMeal != value)
            {
                _savedMeal = value;
                SavedMealId = _savedMeal.Id;      // Manage the relationship to the SavedMeal table

                NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(SavedMealItem));
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region FoodId

    [Column(Order = 3)]
    public int FoodId { get; set; }        

    [ForeignKey(nameof(FoodId))]
    public Food FoodItem
    {
        get => _foodItem;
        set
        {
            if (_foodItem != value)
            {
                _foodItem = value;
                FoodId = _foodItem.Id;          // Manage the relationship to the SavedMeal table

                NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(FoodItem));
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Min

    private int _min = 0;

    [Column(Order = 5)]
    public int Min
    {
        get => _min;
        set
        {
            _min = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(IsValid));
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Max

    private int _max = 0;

    [Column(Order = 6)]
    public int Max
    {
        get => _max;
        set
        {
            _max = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(IsValid));
        }
    }

    #endregion


    #region IsValid

    [NotMapped]
    [Column(Order = 8)]
    public bool IsValid { get => Max >= Min; }

    #endregion



    #region Eventing

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion                
}
```

```cs
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Food> Foods { get; set; }

    public DbSet<SavedMeal> SavedMeals { get; set; }

    public DbSet<FoodSelection> FoodSelections { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

Foodes are stored before creating FoodSelections for a SavedMeal. So when I create a new FoodSelection no new Food should be created.

My problem right now is how I have to do Updates on these tables to be able to save them without Problems.

Internally, I have an ObservableRangeCollection which contains the Foods that are currently selected to be saved as a new SavedMeal or to be used to update an existing SavedMeal. So, I can also load a SavedMeal which contains the FoodSelection (connected with different Foods then). Based from this, I want to add new Foods to the selection or remove Foods from the selection, change Parameters that are stored in FoodSelection and then maybe saved it as a new SavedMeal or just overwrite an existing one.

The Problem I am having is, when I call DatabaseContext.SaveChanges() is that I sometimes get an Exception with a UNIQUE Constraint, which tells me that it tries to add a new Food with the same Name which results in a UNIQUE Constraint Violation. But there should not be an Update on the Food Table at all at this point.

I also had different other problems for instance that values I replaced and set by just assigning them we not saved in the Table unless I retrieved an Entity object and did a SetValues(savedMeal) which is totally unnatural.

```cs
var entity = _databaseService.DatabaseContext.Find(typeof(SavedMeal), savedMeal.Id);
_databaseService.DatabaseContext.Entry(entity).CurrentValues.SetValues(savedMeal);
```

The methods I use to decide if I want to overwrite/update a SaveMeal with the FoodSelections or create a new one with the FoodSelections I have in my internal FoodSelections OverservableRangeCollection are as follows:

```cs
private async Task SaveDataBase()
{
    bool savedChangesSuccessfully = false;

    SavedMeal savedMeal = _databaseService.DatabaseContext.SavedMeals.Where(x => x.Name == SelectedMealName).FirstOrDefault();

    if (savedMeal != null)
    {
        _errorHandlingService.AddErrorCallback(SQLitePCL.raw.SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE, async (updateException) =>
        {
            // DisplayAlert
        });


        bool overwrite = await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(AppResources.AppTitle, Translate(AppResources.CalculateMacros_MealAlreadyExistingOverwriteMessage, savedMeal.Name), AppResources.DialogButton_Yes, AppResources.DialogButton_No);
        if (overwrite)
        {
            UpdateSavedMealWithFoodSelections(savedMeal);

            var entity = _databaseService.DatabaseContext.Find(typeof(SavedMeal), savedMeal.Id);
            _databaseService.DatabaseContext.Entry(entity).CurrentValues.SetValues(savedMeal);

            savedChangesSuccessfully = _databaseService.SaveChanges();
            if (savedChangesSuccessfully)
            {
                // DisplayAlert
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var meal = new SavedMeal();

        meal.Name = SelectedMealName;

        UpdateSavedMealWithFoodSelections(meal);

        _databaseService.DatabaseContext.SavedMeals.Add(meal);
        savedChangesSuccessfully = _databaseService.SaveChanges();
        if (savedChangesSuccessfully)
        {
            // Display Success Message
        }
    }
}

public void UpdateSavedMealWithFoodSelections(SavedMeal meal)
{
    meal.MacroNutrientRatio_MaxProteins = ProteinsMax;
    meal.MacroNutrientRatio_MaxFats = FatsMax;
    meal.MacroNutrientRatio_MaxCarbohydrates = CarbohydratesMax;

    // Remove any FoodSelections that no longer exists
    var removedFoodSelections = meal.FoodSelections.Where(fs => !SelectedFoodItems.Any(ufs => ufs.Id == fs.Id)).ToList();
    foreach (var removedFoodSelection in removedFoodSelections)
    {
        meal.FoodSelections.Remove(removedFoodSelection);
    }


    // Update the remaining FoodSelections
    foreach (var foodSelection in SelectedFoodItems)
    {
        var existingFoodSelection = meal.FoodSelections.FirstOrDefault(fs => fs.Id == foodSelection.Id);

        if (existingFoodSelection != null)
        {
            var existingFoodItem = _databaseService.DatabaseContext.Find(typeof(Food), existingFoodSelection.FoodItem.Id);
            if (existingFoodItem != null)
            {
                var entry = _databaseService.DatabaseContext.Entry(existingFoodItem);
                if (entry != null)
                {
                    entry.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                }
            }

            existingFoodSelection.Min = foodSelection.Min;
            existingFoodSelection.Max = foodSelection.Max;
            existingFoodSelection.OptimalAmount = foodSelection.OptimalAmount;
        }
        else
        {
            // Find the FoodItem and get its reference
            var existingFoodItem = _databaseService.DatabaseContext.Find(typeof(Food), foodSelection.FoodItem.Id);
            if (existingFoodItem != null)
            {
                var entry = _databaseService.DatabaseContext.Entry(existingFoodItem);
                if (entry != null)
                {
                    entry.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                }

                var newFoodSelection = new FoodSelection();
                newFoodSelection.FoodId = ((Food)existingFoodItem).Id;
                newFoodSelection.FoodItem = (Food)existingFoodItem;
                newFoodSelection.Min = foodSelection.Min;
                newFoodSelection.Max = foodSelection.Max;
                newFoodSelection.OptimalAmount = foodSelection.OptimalAmount;

                meal.FoodSelections.Add(newFoodSelection);
            }
        }
    }


    meal.LastSavedDate = DateTime.Now;
}
```

As I am totally confused now and having a hard time to SaveChanges() I wanted to ask in general how I have do Updates on the Tables in an n:m Relationship? The scenario I can't finish successfully is

Foods-Table is up to date with all available Foods and needs no change anymore. The FoodSelections are managed internally or are available from a loaded SavedMeal. So, the values just need an update or we have to create a new FoodSelection from an existing one and need to connect with a new or existing SavedMeal.

How would this be done in the Entity Framework?

==== Update: Fix for Navigation Properties ====

```cs
[Index(nameof(Name), IsUnique = true)]
public class Food
{
    ...

    public virtual List<FoodSelection> FoodSelections { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class FoodSelection : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ...
    
    #region SavedMealItem

    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public int SavedMealId { get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey(nameof(SavedMealId))]
    public virtual SavedMeal SavedMealItem
    {
        get => _savedMeal;
        set
        {
            if (_savedMeal != value)
            {
                _savedMeal = value;
                SavedMealId = _savedMeal.Id;      // Manage the relationship to the SavedMeal table

                NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(SavedMealItem));
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region FoodItem

    [Column(Order = 3)]
    public int FoodId { get; set; }        

    [ForeignKey(nameof(FoodId))]
    public virtual Food FoodItem
    {
        get => _foodItem;
        set
        {
            if (_foodItem != value)
            {
                _foodItem = value;
                FoodId = _foodItem.Id;          // Manage the relationship to the SavedMeal table

                NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(FoodItem));
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion

    ...
}
```

```cs
[Index(nameof(Name), IsUnique = true)]
public class SavedMeal
{
    ...

    public virtual List<FoodSelection> FoodSelections { get; set; }
}
```

**Setting the Navigation Properties for the new FoodSelection**:

```cs
public void UpdateSavedMealWithFoodSelections(SavedMeal meal)
{
    meal.MacroNutrientRatio_MaxProteins = ProteinsMax;
    meal.MacroNutrientRatio_MaxFats = FatsMax;
    meal.MacroNutrientRatio_MaxCarbohydrates = CarbohydratesMax;

    meal.FoodSelections.Clear();


    // Update/Add the remaining SelectedFoodItems that are new
    foreach (var foodSelection in SelectedFoodItems)
    {
        var newFoodSelection = new FoodSelection();
        newFoodSelection.SavedMealId = meal.Id;
        newFoodSelection.SavedMealItem = meal;
        newFoodSelection.FoodId = foodSelection.FoodItem.Id;
        newFoodSelection.FoodItem = foodSelection.FoodItem;
        newFoodSelection.Min = foodSelection.Min;
        newFoodSelection.Max = foodSelection.Max;
        newFoodSelection.OptimalAmount = foodSelection.OptimalAmount;

        //foodSelection.FoodItem.FoodSelections.Add(newFoodSelection);


        meal.FoodSelections.Add(newFoodSelection);
    }


    meal.LastSavedDate = DateTime.Now;
}
```

When I call SaveChanges() I the an Exception with message "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.". When I look through the different references and Lists of my SavedMeal in Debugger, I do not see any "null" value.

==== Update 2: Removed assignment of FoodId/SavedMealId ====

```cs
#region SavedMealItem

[Column(Order = 2)]
public int SavedMealId { get; set; }

[ForeignKey(nameof(SavedMealId))]
public virtual SavedMeal SavedMealItem
{
    get => _savedMeal;
    set
    {
        if (_savedMeal != value)
        {
            _savedMeal = value;

            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(SavedMealItem));
        }
    }
}

#endregion

#region FoodItem

[Column(Order = 3)]
public int FoodId { get; set; }        

[ForeignKey(nameof(FoodId))]
public virtual Food FoodItem
{
    get => _foodItem;
    set
    {
        if (_foodItem != value)
        {
            _foodItem = value;

            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(FoodItem));
        }
    }
}

#endregion
```

Could this still be fine...

```cs
public List<FoodSelection> FoodSelections { get; set; }
```

... or using a virtual approach like this

```cs
public virtual List<FoodSelection> FoodSelections { get; set; }
```

... or better do a lazy loading approach like this?

```cs
private List<FoodSelection> _foodSelections;
public virtual List<FoodSelection> FoodSelections
{
    get
    {
        return this._foodSelections ?? (this._foodSelections = new List<FoodSelection>());

    }
}
```

I think the most important part regarding the updates is to remove the FoodSelections from the Database that are no longer connected with a SavedMeal I want to update:

```cs
public void UpdateFoodSelections(SavedMeal meal)
{
    meal.MacroNutrientRatio_MaxProteins = ProteinsMax;
    meal.MacroNutrientRatio_MaxFats = FatsMax;
    meal.MacroNutrientRatio_MaxCarbohydrates = CarbohydratesMax;

    // Delete available FoodSelections that are not selected anymore
    var foodSelectionIdsToRemove = meal.FoodSelections.Select(fs => fs.Id).Except(SelectedFoodItems.Select(f => f.Id)).ToList();
    foreach (var idToRemove in foodSelectionIdsToRemove)
    {
        var foodSelectionToRemove = meal.FoodSelections.FirstOrDefault(fs => fs.Id == idToRemove);
        if (foodSelectionToRemove != null)
        {
            _databaseService.DatabaseContext.Remove(foodSelectionToRemove);
        }
    }

    // Update/Add remaining SelectedFoodItems that are new
    foreach (var foodSelection in SelectedFoodItems)
    {
        FoodSelection existingFoodSelection = meal.FoodSelections.FirstOrDefault(fs => fs.Id == foodSelection.Id);

        if (existingFoodSelection != null)
        {
            // Update existing FoodSelection
            var existingFoodItem = _databaseService.DatabaseContext.Find(typeof(Food), foodSelection.FoodItem.Id);
            if (existingFoodItem != null)
            {
                existingFoodSelection.FoodId = ((Food)existingFoodItem).Id;
                existingFoodSelection.FoodItem = (Food)existingFoodItem;
                existingFoodSelection.Min = foodSelection.Min;
                existingFoodSelection.Max = foodSelection.Max;
                existingFoodSelection.OptimalAmount = foodSelection.OptimalAmount;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Add new FoodSelection
            var newFoodSelection = new FoodSelection
            {
                SavedMealId = meal.Id,
                SavedMealItem = meal,
                FoodId = foodSelection.FoodItem.Id,
                FoodItem = foodSelection.FoodItem,
                Min = foodSelection.Min,
                Max = foodSelection.Max,
                OptimalAmount = foodSelection.OptimalAmount
            };

            meal.FoodSelections.Add(newFoodSelection);
        }
    }

    meal.LastSavedDate = DateTime.Now;
}
```

Comment: Start from fixing navigation properties. You should NOT initialize navigation reference properties, like `SavedMealItem` and `FoodItem`. It is EF Core rule, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20773057/10646316) for more details.

Comment: What I basically wanted to do was just add the SavedMealId and FoodId for a FoodSelection. With FoodItems or Foods, I did not want do to anything here. When I got Exceptions that told me references are missing, I started doing that. But currently, I would say there are also strange things for me, like setting Entities „Unchanged“ or having to use SetValues(…). Is this really the way to go for updates in EF?

Comment: Do you hear me? Fix navigation properties. EF going crazy if they are initialized.

Comment: I hope I hear you and understand your point. I heard I should remove the Initialization of the Lists used as Backreferences with an empty List. I also used the ```virtual``` keyword to use them with Lazy Loading. I also did an Update of my ```UpdateSavedMealWithFoodSelections``` method. There, I do not know if you thought I should change my code also. But, in my opinion I either need the ```SavedMealId ``` and ```FoodId``` in a new FoodSelection or both and also the ```SavedMealItem``` and ```FoodItem```references. I get an ```Object reference not set to an instance of an object.``` Exception

Comment: Not lists! References. And yes, you have to handle null references exceptions somehow. Better to introduce ViewModel, instead of reusing Model classes.

Comment: You are confusing me! When talking about references there is only class ```FoodSelection``` in which I have references like ```FoodItem``` and ```SavedMealItem```. These are set and initialized with corresponding value (reference) in ```UpdateSavedMealWithFoodSelections(SavedMeal meal)``` I showed above. Why then emitting this Exception? When I set a breakpoint to this property setter I can see that ```FoodId = _foodItem.Id;``` is the troublemaker as obviously it assigned a "null" value to this property. But why is this? I did assign a value before and see it in Debugger.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv - I updated my code regarding assignment in the Navigation Reference you probably were talking about in **Update 2** of my question. Also regarding lazy loading approach I had a question. Maybe you can tell what you think about that or you see some downsides with the different approaches