# issue inserting data to joining table of many to many in EF Core and .NET 8

Tags: postgresql, join, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, many-to-many

I have my models configured as below:

```
public class Order
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; } = null!;
    public DkUser User { get; set; } = null!;
    public int ShippingStatusId { get; set; }
    public ShippingStatus ShippingStatus { get; set; } = null!;
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public string? CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string? UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; } = new List<Product>();
    public ICollection<OrderDetail> OrderDetails {get; set;} = [];
}

public class Product
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Model { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public float Price { get; set; }
    public int View { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category? Category { get; set; }
    public int DiscountId { get; set; }
    public Discount Discount { get; set; } = null!;
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public string? CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string? UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; } = new List<Order>();
    public ICollection<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; } = [];
    public ICollection<ProductPicture> ProductPictures { get; set; } = new List<ProductPicture>();
}

public class OrderDetail
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; } = new();
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public Order Order { get; set; } = new();
    public int Amount { get; set; }
}

class DkdbContext(DbContextOptions<DkdbContext> options) : IdentityDbContext<DkUser>(options)
{
    public DbSet<Computer> Computers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Discount> Discounts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ShippingStatus> ShippingStatuses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProductPicture> ProductPictures { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DkUser> DkUsers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<Computer>()
            .HasKey(c => c.Id);
        builder.Entity<Computer>()
            .Property(c => c.Id)
            .HasColumnType("uuid");

        builder.Entity<Category>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Products)
            .WithOne(e => e.Category)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.CategoryId)
            .IsRequired();

        builder.Entity<Product>()
            .HasOne(e => e.Discount)
            .WithMany(e => e.Products)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.DiscountId)
            .IsRequired();

        builder.Entity<Product>()
            .Property(e => e.CreatedDate)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("current_timestamp");
        builder.Entity<Product>()
            .Property(e => e.UpdatedDate)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("current_timestamp");
        builder.Entity<Product>()
            .Property(e => e.View)
            .HasDefaultValue(1);

        builder.Entity<Order>()
           .Property(e => e.CreatedDate)
           .HasDefaultValueSql("current_timestamp");
        builder.Entity<Order>()
            .Property(e => e.UpdatedDate)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("current_timestamp");
        builder.Entity<Order>()
            .Property(e => e.ShippingStatusId)
            .HasDefaultValue(1);

        builder.Entity<ProductPicture>()
            .HasOne(e => e.Product)
            .WithMany(e => e.ProductPictures)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.ProductId)
            .IsRequired();

        // order detail config
        builder.Entity<Product>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Orders)
            .WithMany(e => e.Products)
            .UsingEntity<OrderDetail>();

        builder.Entity<OrderDetail>()
            .Property(e => e.Amount)
            .HasDefaultValue(1);

        // end order detail config

        builder.Entity<ShippingStatus>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Orders)
            .WithOne(e => e.ShippingStatus)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.ShippingStatusId);

        builder.Entity<DkUser>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Orders)
            .WithOne(e => e.User)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.UserId);
    }
}
```

I want to create a new order with 2 products and corresponding amount specified. Here is how I implemented that:

```
public class OrderEnpoint
{
    public static void Map(WebApplication app)
    {
        app.MapPost("/order", async (DkdbContext db, OrderDto orderRequest, UserManager<DkUser> userManager) =>
        {
            if (orderRequest == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(orderRequest.UserId))
                return Results.BadRequest();

            var user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(orderRequest.UserId);

            var newOrder = new Order
            {
                UserId = orderRequest.UserId,
                CreatedBy = user?.UserName,
                UpdatedBy = user?.UserName,
            };

            await db.Orders.AddAsync(newOrder);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();

            var _OrderDetails = orderRequest.ProductOrderList
                .Select(e => new OrderDetail
                {
                    OrderId = newOrder.Id,
                    ProductId = e.ProductId,
                    Amount = e.Amount,
                }).ToList();

            await db.OrderDetails.AddRangeAsync(_OrderDetails);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();

            return Results.Created();
        });
    }
}
```

Here is my data transfer object class:

```
public class OrderDto
{
    public string UserId { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public List<OrderRequest> ProductOrderList { get; set; } = [];
}

public class OrderRequest
{
    [Required]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Amount { get; set; }
}
```

When I debug this code, I am able to see order record created in the `Orders` table, but not in the `OrderDetails`. I am using postgres as database.

Here is what the error look like:

> Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 23502: null value in column "UserId" of relation "Orders" violates not-null constraint
>
> DETAIL: Failing row contains (15, null, 1, 2024-01-01 14:07:25.091254+00, 2024-01-01 14:07:25.091254+00, null, null).
>
> Exception data:
> Severity: ERROR
> SqlState: 23502
> MessageText: null value in column "UserId" of relation "Orders"  violates not-null constraint
>
> Detail: Failing row contains (15, null, 1, 2024-01-01 14:07:25.091254+00, 2024-01-01 14:07:25.091254+00, null, null).
> SchemaName: public
> TableName: Orders
> ColumnName: UserId
> File: execMain.c
> Line: 2003
> Routine: ExecConstraints

I expect to be able to create a new `Order` with associated `OrderDetail` with amount respectively. I am looking for solutions, am glad if someone can help. Thank you.

Comment: "I am able to see order record created in Orders table" -- Are you sure? The exception is about the Orders table. BTW, you don't need two `SaveChangesAsync` calls. You can assign the OrderDetails directly to the new Order and save once.

Comment: Hi @GertArnold SaveChangesAsync is used twice in the current code because the newOrder's Id appears to be self-incrementing and is generated after it is saved, depending on the business design.

Comment: @JasonPan Sure, and EF will use the generated key and figure out the order of statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue will be this in OrderDetail:

```
public Order Order { get; set; } = new();
```

This is initializing the navigation property to a new Order which will have an ID of 0, [Edit: as well as a UserId of 0 and any other FKs that it will attempt to use as a FK for the order detail even though you are setting the FK explicitly. So in adding the OrderDetail it will try inserting a new empty order rather than reference the existing one you first insert resulting in FK violations since that new empty order has no details set.]

Change this to:

```
public Order Order { get; set; } = null!;
```

The same applies to the Product reference as well. With entities you should only ever initialize Collection navigation properties, never individual references. Also when setting references where you have a FK and navigation property, use one or the other, ideally you should consider using shadow FKs and just use the navigation properties. Multiple SaveChanges should also be avoided. EF can manage FKs and navigation properties in one go, so the better approach is to let EF manage the FKs:

```
        if (orderRequest == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(orderRequest.UserId))
            return Results.BadRequest();

        var user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(orderRequest.UserId);
        if (user == null) // a good idea to check that the user is actually valid.
            return Results.BadRequest();
      
        var newOrder = new Order
        {
            User = user,
            CreatedBy = user.UserName,
            UpdatedBy = user.UserName,
        };

        var orderDetails = orderRequest.ProductOrderList
            .Select(e => new OrderDetail
            {
                ProductId = e.ProductId,
                Amount = e.Amount,
            }).ToList();

        foreach(var orderDetail in orderDetails)
           newOrder.OrderDetails.Add(orderDetail);

        db.Orders.Add(newOrder);

        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Results.Created();
```

EF will insert the order and order details together and link up the FKs automatically.

Comment: Well spotted! Even though I've been aware of this issue [for years](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20773057/861716) I often overlook it in someone else's code. I think the consequences are a bit different than what you describe though. In the second SaveChanges, EF tries to save a new Order which, obviously, doesn't have a UserId set, so it fails even before making it to saving OrderDetails.

Comment: Yeah, updated the answer as that new Order reference initialized on the OrderDetail will attempt to insert the new Order rather than associate via the FK and that new order will lack the userID and any other FKs that were set up for the initial order. Ultimately the best fix is to set the navigation references and let EF handle the FKs, but always avoid initializing the singular navigation properties to prevent surprises like this. :)

Answer (score 0):

The error should occur in the following code, and it is recommended to set a breakpoint to check the status of the user.

```
if (orderRequest == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(orderRequest.UserId))
    return Results.BadRequest();
// need to make sure  the user is not null
var user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(orderRequest.UserId);

var newOrder = new Order
{
    UserId = orderRequest.UserId,
    CreatedBy = user?.UserName,
    UpdatedBy = user?.UserName,
};
```

**So the modified code is as follows：**

```
app.MapPost("/order", async (DkdbContext db, OrderDto orderRequest, UserManager<DkUser> userManager) =>
{
    
    if (orderRequest == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(orderRequest.UserId))
        return Results.BadRequest("Invalid order request or UserId is empty");

    // find user by useid
    var user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(orderRequest.UserId);
    
    if (user == null)
        return Results.BadRequest("User not found");

    
    var newOrder = new Order
    {
        UserId = orderRequest.UserId,
        CreatedBy = user.UserName,
        UpdatedBy = user.UserName,
    };

    
    await db.Orders.AddAsync(newOrder);
   
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();

    
    var _OrderDetails = orderRequest.ProductOrderList
        .Select(e => new OrderDetail
        {
            OrderId = newOrder.Id,
            ProductId = e.ProductId,
            Amount = e.Amount,
        }).ToList();

    
    await db.OrderDetails.AddRangeAsync(_OrderDetails);
    
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    return Results.Created();
});
```