# Is there a more convenient way to achieve one to many relationship?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I struggle with some basic concepts of EF Core. I want to achieve an one-to-many relationship between Customer and Order. My idea is that a customer can have an account without any orders but an order needs an existing account.

Looking at following code:

```cs
public class Customer
{
        public Customer(string firstName, string lastName,
            DateOnly birthday, string mail, string phoneNumber,
            string password, Address address, Gender gender)
        {
            FirstName = firstName;
            LastName = lastName;
            Birthday = birthday;
            Mail = mail;
            PhoneNumber = phoneNumber;
            Password = password;
            Gender = gender;
            Address = address;
        }

        protected Customer() { }

        public CustomerId Id { get; private set; } = default!;
        public string Firstname { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string Lastname { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public DateOnly Birthday { get; set; }
        public string Mail { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string Password { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public Address Address { get; set; } = default!;
        public Gender Gender { get; set; } = default!;
        protected List<Order> _orders = new();
        public IReadOnlyCollection<Order> Orders => _orders;
    }


public class Order
{
    public Order()
    {
        // What here?
    }

    protected Order()
    {
    }
    
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public DateOnly OrderDate { get; private set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; private set; } = default!;
    public Customer CustomerId { get; private set; }
}
```

I don't know what to put into the constructor of the Order class. I already read through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20757594/ef-codefirst-should-i-initialize-navigation-properties) but it is not so clear for me. Do I have to put the CustomerId property into the constructor? Because I don't want that somebody can create a Order without an Customer.

Comment: `CustomerId` is not nullable so it won't be possible to create an `Order` without a valid `CustomerId`. You *could* add a constructor that accepts a `Customer` object, that's not the same thing as creating a new customer in the constructor, which the referred answer warns against.

Comment: @GertArnold So to be sure that means I could always do something like `Customer = customer` but not Customer = new Customer();? You wrote "You could add a constructor that accepts a Customer object," that leads me to the point why the `Order` should be able to manage customers, shouldn't it be vice-verse since Customer manages its own orders through like maybe adding it to the list and ef core inserts the order into the `Order` table in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I design entities, they serve as the Domain so I want to ensure that at a low level they help enforce rules to ensure that when an order is created it is always created in an valid state, and when any entity is edited, it is always kept in a valid state. It seems your intent is along similar lines.

Some suggestions I can offer:

1. When exposing public constructors, anything that is required values and relations (non-nullable) should be passed in via the constructor. Basically a new instance should be able to be persisted the moment it is created.
2. Avoid null-able forgiveness in your entities. (`!`) Your public constructor should satisfy these, and you can mark your protected default constructor (to keep EF happy) with the `#oragma ignore` for the compiler check. This includes defaulting properties to invalid values like `string.Empty`if those values are not valid. If a property is optional/null-able then mark it as nullable (`?`)

.

```
#pragma warning disable CS8618 // Non-nullable field must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring as nullable.
    protected Order()
    { }
#pragma warning restore CS8618 // Non-nullable field must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring as nullable.
```

3. Avoid exposing both FKs and navigation properties. Use one or the other. For most relationships I use navigation properties with shadow FKs, where other times where I don't need a navigation property, I will just expose the FK for a little more performance. (For instance lookup table many-to-one where I will have the lookup "entities" cached so something like an OrderStatus on Order would just have an OrderStatus Enum FK and if I need details about the status to display I can pull it from a read-only cache rather than Order.OrderStatus.Name, etc.  The reason to avoid using both FKs and navigation properties is that they form two sources of truth. You have Order.CustomerId and Order.Customer.Id. (In your example there is a bug that CustomerId is defined as type `Customer` instead of `CustomerId`) Orders should probably never change Customers, but if they could you get weird what-if scenarios like what wins if you set both a Customer reference and a CustomerId to different values?
4. Protect required setters and consider controlling updates with methods. Optional values that don't have special meaning and can be adjusted independently can have public setters, but for required fields and related data consider updater methods. For example take an address entity with a Street, City, State, and Postcode. If these had setters it is possible to change a city without altering a State or Postcode which should ultimately be expected to be updated if a city changes. You may have had an address validation lookup prior to updating the domain and intend to update all necessary properties. The domain can set the expectation to at least remind developers that it expects all fields:

.

```
public string Street { get; protected set; }
public string City { get; protected set; }
public string State { get; protected set; }
public string Postcode { get; protected set; }

public Update(string street, string city, string state, string postcode)
{
    ArgumentException.ThrowIfNullOrEmpty(street, nameof(street));
    ArgumentException.ThrowIfNullOrEmpty(city, nameof(city));
    ArgumentException.ThrowIfNullOrEmpty(state, nameof(state));
    ArgumentException.ThrowIfNullOrEmpty(postcode, nameof(postcode));

    Street = street;
    City = city;
    State = state;
    Postcode = postcode;
}
```

**Edit**: Factory method approach.

For entities that are dependents of an aggregate root, one option is to have the aggregate root expose a method to manage the creation and association of that entity. For instance if within an order we can add an OrderLine which is a Product reference and a Quantity, the constructor for OrderLine can be marked `internal` and Order can expose a method "AddOrderLine(Product product, int quantity)". The advantage of this that the Order can validate details such as whether an order line for that product already exists, and what to do if it does. The caveat of working with approaches like this is that the expectation should be that Order.OrderLines is eager loaded before this method can be called. This can be a bit messy to determine within the scope of an Order, but I always have lazy loading enabled as a fallback. Lazy loading the Orderlines collection is not ideal, but it is preferable to having misleading behaviour if the method is possibly called on an Order that did vs. did not eager load the order lines. Lazy loading calls are something I do regularly scan profiler output for during development and testing.

For aggregate roots like an Order or Customer I will have a factory method. Typically I make this a responsibility of my Repository serving the Controller/Service, so the factory might have:

```
public async Task<Order> CreateOrder(int customerId, /* other required fields */)
{
    var customer = await Context.Customers
        .Include(x => x.Orders)
        .Single(x => x.CustomerId == customerId);
    return await CreateOrder(customer, /* other required fields */);
}

public async Task<Order> CreateOrder(Customer customer, /* other required fields */)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(customer, nameof(customer));
    // Guard all required fields....

    // Perform any additional validation checks, load/lookup any additional references...

    var order = new Order(/* required fields */);
    customer.Orders.Add(order);
    Context.SaveChanges(); 
    return order;
}
```

The `SaveChanges` against the DbContext occurs within the scope of a Unit of Work, so it performs a final validation to ensure the data is in a state it can be persisted, but the actual persistence will not occur until the UoW is committed. If there is a problem with the data state then it should come up within this CreateOrder method rather than just when the unit of work `SaveChanges` actually tries to commit the change.

Comment: In point 1 where you say relation should be passed I think you mean the entity not the foreign key right? I saw a lot of different approaches in the internet where somebody adds the `Order` to the orders list through an Add method in the `Customer` class which confusses me when to pass it with the constructor and when to add it to the list

Comment: Yes, it goes with point #3 to avoid exposing both FK and navigation property. If it makes sense that orders only belong to a customer then you could have a more DDD approach and an AddOrder method on Customer to manage new orders through Customer, it would depend on you intended workflow.  Does a user find a customer and add an order for them, or create an order and associate it to a customer? Personally I use factories for aggregate root entities which accept all required fields and can perform necessary lookups and associations.

Comment: I have added an example of a factory method approach I use for aggregate root entities.  It shows a shared aggregate root where Orders and Customers are peers so the new order is added to Customer.Orders. In case we might associate the order to a loaded customer. If not, then the Id variant can be the only method where the Customer is fetched, associated to a new order, and the order is added to the Context.Orders `DbSet` if Order should serve as a purely aggregate root.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your comments which helped me a lot. The only thing which I don't understand is why I would need the method with the `CustomerId`. I have no experience in ASP.NET yet, but isn't it possible to get the loged in customer and just use `this` in the `CreateOrder(Customer customer, /* other required fields */)` method?

Comment: Yes, you could if you always pre-fetch the customer prior to calling it. The reason for an ID version is for cases like in web applications where you have a controller action that receives parameters such as a CustomerId. Passing entities back and forth may seem simpler, but deserialized entities passed back from a view etc. are *not* tracked entities and likely are not complete, so these lead to all kinds of problems if your code assumes the DbContext scoped to the request handling the action should be treating them as existing, tracked instances.