# Instantiate entity framework database collections

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Do I have and if yes in which scenarios do I have to instantiate a entity framework database collection.

I use code first approach.

I see different usages all around but I assume thats because nobody knows...

```
public class Company
{
    public Company()
    {
        Employees = new HashSet<Employee>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ISet<Employee> Employees{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please provide us with what you've tried so far. Secondly: Your question is not clear in the current form, could you please be more verbose?

Comment: Tried so far??? Its a simple question. Do I have to instantiate that HashSet or not. Both code work the question is do I HAVE to instantiate it and why?

Comment: Doest [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9247069/1608705) help?  As for trying yourself: [_Explain how you encountered the problem you're trying to solve, and any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself._](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do that to be able to create a new entity which has dependent entities in the collection. You instantiate a new `CarOwner` entity for example, which is just a C# object and since you explicitly create it, don't have it materialized by Entity Framework through a query for you, you also need to set up all fields just as you would with any other C# object. By also instantiating its `Cars` collection, you can add `Car` instances to it before persisting it using `SaveChanges`.