# Can't create related entity in ASP.NET Core with EF Core

Tags: entity-framework, azure, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I have a problem creating a related entity in Entity Framework Core 2.0. I've just created the solution, consisting of an Asp.Net Core backend project, and a UWP project to act as client. Both solutions share model. The two models are:

```
public class UnitOfWork {
    public int UnitOfWorkId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Human Human { get; set; }
}

public class Human {
    public int HumanId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<UnitOfWork> WorkDone { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, model is very simple. One `human` has many `units of work`. By the way, the backend is connected to an Azure SQL database. I've seen the migration classes, and the database schema looks good to me.

The problem I have is when I want to create a `unit of work` referencing an existing `human`, using HTTP. The controller is fairly simple:

```
[HttpPost]
public UnitOfWork Post([FromBody] UnitOfWork unitOfWork) {
    using (var db = new DatabaseContext()) {
        db.UnitsOfWork.Add(unitOfWork);
        var count = db.SaveChanges();
        Console.WriteLine("{0} records saved to database", count);
    }
    return unitOfWork;
}
```

Again, nothing fancy here.

How can I create an unit of work, and assign it to an existing human? If I try it with an existing human, in this way

```
var humans = await Api.GetHumans();
var firstHuman = humans.First();

var unitOfWorkToCreate = new UnitOfWork() {
    Name = TbInput.Text,
    Human = firstHuman,
};
```

I get this error:

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Humans' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

I feel that setting IDENTITY_INSERT to ON will solve my problem, but this is not what I want to do. In the client, I'll select an existing `human`, write down a name for the `unit of work`, and create the latter. Is this the correct way to proceed?

EDIT: Following @Ivan Stoev answer, I've updated the `UnitOfWork` controller to attach `unitofwork.Human`. This led to

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Unexpected end when deserializing array. Path 'human.workDone', line 1, position 86.'

Investigating - seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9247069/1096905) - EFCore expects to create collections (like `human.WorkDone`) in the constructor, so I did it, and no more nulls deserializing. However, now I have a self-referencing loop:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Self referencing loop detected with type 'PlainWorkTracker.Models.UnitOfWork'. Path 'human.workDone'.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operation in question is falling into [Saving Disconnected Entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/disconnected-entities) category.

`Add` methods marks all entities in the graph which are not currently tracked as new (`Added`) and then `SaveChanges` will try to insert them in the database.

You need a way to tell EF that `unitOfWork.Human` is an existing entity. The simplest way to achieve that is to `Attach` it (which will mark it as `Unchanged`, i.e. existing) to the context before calling `Add`:

```
db.Attach(unitOfWork.Human);
db.Add(unitOfWork);
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks! But now I had a `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Unexpected end when deserializing array. Path 'human.workDone', line 1, position 86.'`. I've added the attach line just as you said, in the code posted in my question

Comment: This is something different. Can you debug if `Post` method is hit and  `unitOfWork.Human.WorkDone` contains items?

Comment: I've just updated my original question, please revisit

Comment: Well, as I said, that's a different issue  which you need to solve for operations returning such entities. You can find many similar posts on SO, you'd need basically to either configure `ReferenceLoopHandling` property of the serializer or switch using DTOs / ViewModels.